# redmine + github how to connect and work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, redmine

Help me. I have access to the FTP server on which the redmine, I need to copy the project redmine in github and somehow to bridge them together to work on redmine in github. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can download project via `ssh` and than initialize  project with git `git init`. Also install `git` on remote machine, and use it as usual git repository(`git pull/push`)